# Publishing Infopath forms Issue: Invalid URL

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

`http://vikbehal:7/sites/Sneham/` this is the URL of my web-portal. While publishing a infopath form, it is giving error, `"Invalid Location http://vikbehal:7/sites/Sneham/_layouts/viewlsts.aspx"`

Comment: What happens, when you open the `http://vikbehal:7/sites/Sneham/_layouts/viewlsts.aspx` URL? Is page opening or are you redirected to `http://vikbehal:7/sites/Sneham/_layouts/1033/viewlsts.aspx` Is this SharePoint after migration from 2007 to 2010?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Need to create site collection at toor level, giving virtual path will not accept path`. so go for `http://mysite/` instead of `http://mysite/sites/xyz`